# Issue performing a lookup based on an input

Tags: python, scripting

The goal of this Python script would be to find the corresponding URL for whichever state that was input. I keep getting these errors during the "Lookup" portion of the script. The name of the input is 'state'.

Please see the below code and trace back.

```
df =pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/PythonScript_Data_medverify.xlsx',sheet_name='STATE_URL_MAP')
df = df.to_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/PythonScript_Data_medverify.xlsx')
stateurl = df[df['State']==state]['URL']
```

Here's the error/traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-df1e8ca01184>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/user.name/.spyder-py3/CREDverifyscript.py', wdir='C:/Users/user.name/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/user.name/.spyder-py3/CREDverifyscript.py", line 23, in <module>
    stateurl = df[df['State']==state]['URL']

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have bug in this line.
- `to_excel` do not return anything. Thats why your `df` is `none` after that statement.

```
df = df.to_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/PythonScript_Data_medverify.xlsx')
```

Change this to this.

```
df.to_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/PythonScript_Data_medverify.xlsx')
```

Comment: That is separate issue from this question. You can accept this answer and open another question for error.